# Surefire 3.0.0-M5 suiteXmlFile not recognized

Tags: maven, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I try to run a testng suite via maven.
This is the plugin within my build dependencies of the pom:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
  <configuration>
        <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>test.xml</suiteXmlFile>
        </suiteXmlFiles>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and that the testng dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>7.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I would expect that with the command:

```
mvn clean test
```

my test.xml is executed. But instead all my unit tests are executed and my test suite is untouched.

In case I change the version of surefire to 2.22.2 and testng 6.10 everything works as expected and the test.xml is used.

How can I fix that with the latest version of surfire and testng?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You fell into [Surefire open bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1841?jql=text%20%7E%20%22suiteXmlFile%22) `<suiteXmlFiles> no longer finds tests starting with 3.0.0-M4`

> TestSuite is discovered and the tests are run. This is on Surefire 3.0.0-M3. If you change to 3.0.0-M4 or higher and run the same command, it will not find the TestSuite at all or run any tests.

Downgrade (until it's fixed) to version 3.0.0-M3 (or lower)